# Show that $f(x)$ is continuous at point $c$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f(x) = 0$ on $[a,b]$ except for $c \in [a,b]$ where $f(c) = 1$.  I am asked to show $f(x)$ is continuous at point $c$.

Thus I have for the definition of continuity:

if $\;|x-c|<\delta\;$ then $\;|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon\;,$

if $\;|x-c|<\delta\;$ then $\;|1|<\varepsilon\;.$

However given that the definition has to hold for all $\varepsilon>0$ then I'm not sure how this applies given that $\varepsilon>1$ by the above and thus there exist some values for which the definition does not hold.

Comment: $f$ isn't continuous at $c$. Is your function correctly defined?

Comment: The reason why there exist some values of $\,\varepsilon\,$ for which the definition does not hold, is that the function is NOT continuous at the point $\,c\,.$

Comment: Are you actually asking about how one could *continuously extend* $f$ at $c$? As Mandelbrot has already mentioned, the function as it is defined right now is *not* continuous at $c$.

Comment: How am I to show F(x) is integrable on [a,b] however?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of continuity: $f$ is continuous at $c$ if *for all* $\epsilon > 0$, *there exists* $\delta > 0$ such that *for all* $x$, if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.

I'm emphasizing the quantifiers.  When you negate a statement, the quantifiers flip and the negation moves down the line.  So $f$ is **not** continuous at $c$ if *there exists* $\epsilon > 0$ such that *for all* $\delta > 0$, *there exists* $x$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(c)| \geq \epsilon$.

If you draw a graph of $f$ and inspect each of these definitions, I think you'll see which one is satisfied, and how.